# What's the meaning of "the sugar-sticks of the sweet-stuff women"?

Tags: meaning

> Good gracious, what a quantity of gold there was! enough to buy all ***the sugar-sticks of the sweet-stuff women***; all the tin soldiers, whips, and rocking-horses in the world, or even the whole town itself There was, indeed, an immense quantity.

Now I'm reading a fairy tale titled "The Tinder-Box", written by Hans Christian Andersen.

I don't understand that italic part.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a creative phrase, but it seems to mean "enough gold to buy all the candy from the women who sell candy."

Sugar sticks probably refers to rock candy on sticks, like those made in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdH577EJdtc

Answer (score 1):

Remember that this is a story for children, and children of 150 years ago. In those days, if children had a little spare money they might spend it on sweets or toys. The sort of sweets that they might buy if they had money were "sugar sticks" (though the original Danish has *Sukkergrise*, (sugar pigs) and *Kagekone* (a biscuit decorated to look like a woman, rather like a gingerbread-woman))

So this really just a list of things that children would find valuable.